# Find the equation of an ellipse given its focus, directrix and eccentricity

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Ellipse has a focus $(3;0)$, a directrix $x+y-1=0$ and an eccentricity of $1/2$.
Find its equation.

I should probably use the fact that $r/d = e$, where $r$ is the distance from the focus to any point $M(x,y)$ of an ellipse. $d$ the distance from $M(x,y)$ to the directrix, and $e$ is the eccentricity. However my attempt failed.

Answer (score 3):

> I should probably use the fact that $r/d = e$, where $r$ is the distance from the focus to any point $M(x,y)$ of an ellipse. $d$ the distance from $M(x,y)$ to the directrix, and $e$ is the eccentricity.

If you showed your attempt to begin with, we might be able to be a bit more helpful; alas, since you haven't shown it, you'll have to content yourself with the following sketch of a solution.

You know the distance from an arbitrary point $(x,y)$ to the focus $(3,0)$:

$$f=\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-0)^2}$$

and you can use the formula for point-line distance (formula 11 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html)) to get the distance from $(x,y)$ to the line $x+y-1=0$:

$$d=\frac{x+y-1}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}$$

from which you use the definition for eccentricity, $\varepsilon=\dfrac{f}{d}$, where $\varepsilon=\dfrac12$.

At once you should obtain an equation with a square root. You can try squaring both sides of the equation and then rearrange things to obtain a two-variable quadratic as usual, but you'll have to justify why the squaring is legal. You should end up with

$$7x^2-2xy+7y^2-46x+2y+71=0$$

Comment: Another possibility is $175x^2-50xy-990x+175y^2+210y+1359=0$: https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/algebra-2/ellipse-calculator/?type=d&f=4x%5E2%2B9y%5E2%3D36&cx=&cy=&f1x=3&f1y=0&f2x=&f2y=&v1x=&v1y=&v2x=&v2y=&cv1x=&cv1y=&cv2x=&cv2y=&ma=&mi=&e=1%2F2&a=&d1=x%2By-1&d2=&p1x=&p1y=&p2x=&p2y=&p3x=&p3y=

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, $e=c/a=1/2$, and the distance from the focus to directrix is $a^2/c-c$. So it is easy to calculate a and c. And you will find the solution.